# Function parameter calibrations by means machine learning

Tags: optimization, calibration, hyperparameters

I have a function F, [bool] = F(DATASET, tresh1, tresh2), 
that take input a DATASET and some parameters, for exasemple 2 treshold value  -tresh1 e tresh2-, and returns a boolean: 1 if DATASET is "good", 0 otherwise. The answer depends on the values tresh1 e tresh2 of course.

Suppose I have 100 DATASETs avaiable and I know which ones are good and which are not. I would like to "train" my function F, i.e. teach it a couple of value tresh1_ and tresh2_ such that F(DATASET, tresh1_, tresh2_) returns "true" for all (or most of) DATASETs "good" and "false" otherwize.

I expect that F(DATASET_, tresh1_, tresh2_), where DATASET_ is a new one (different from the previous 100), return me true if DATASET_ is really "good".

I could see that problem as a clustering problem: for every DATASET in the training set I choose random tresh1 and tresh2 and I mark which values makes sure that F returns correct value and which not. Hence I select a region where tresh1 and tresh2 values are "good".
Is that a good method? Are there better ones?

In general, it seems to me a "parameters calibration problem". Does exist some classic tecniques to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is commonly known as

### [Hyperparameter optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization)

See the Wikipedia article for details. The common approach is to perform a **grid search**, unless you can compute the *derivatives* of your function F.

This is a search method; it is commonly used in machine learning to optimize the performance, but it is not a "machine learning" algorithm itself.

Comment: thanks! a releted key-concept is SVD (support vector machines), very interesting.

Comment: No, that SVMs are not a related key concept, but a **use case**. SVMs (not SVD) have multiple parameters that need to be chosen for good performance... SVD (singular value decomposition) is something else.